# Missing ordering code in VISHAY mosfets

Tags: components, identification

Anybody has an idea of what the GE3 and RE3 stand for on Vishay mosfets order code?, for example the SIR870ADP can be ordered as either SIR870ADP-T1-GE3 or SIR870ADP-T1-RE3

The datasheet only mentions SiR870ADP-T1-GE3 to be "Lead (Pb)-free and Halogen-free" and I cannot find anywhere what the T1-RE3 ordering code means

Product page: http://www.vishay.com/product?docid=63657&tab=quality

Datasheet: http://www.vishay.com/docs/63657/sir870adp.pdf

Comment: Contact page: http://www.vishay.com/company/contacts/

Comment: I've already contacted them but I am in need of a an answer for a purchase order, and of course the part described in the datasheet is out of stock...

Comment: Ouch. Good luck. :|

Comment: Given that the RE3 is marked as "New" on mouser, and the datasheet link goes back to the GE3 one, it's potentially a case of where it was manufactured. Vishay seem to be having supply issues (I've been waiting on some PMOS for 3 months, with lead times growing), but are increasing their manufacturing capacity.

Comment: I believe both of the mosfets are both Lead free and halogen free.
In an excel sheet i found of Vishay products about markings it says:

"How to Order Lead Free Part
(Web)" Add "-E3" or"-Ge3" suffix. Perhaps it has something to do with Re-reeling, cut tape or anything similiar

Comment: That seems to hold true here, In the link above "Product page" in the quality tab you can select the part numbers and both options are specified as lead and halogen free. They seem to be identical so far

Answer (score 1):

Got an answer

> Vishay PPAKSO8 products having “-RE3” suffix means that they use a
>   mold compound that is best suited for thick-board (greater than
>   12-layer) applications where Board-Level Reliability per IPC-9592 is
>   important.

Plus

> both parts perform exactly the same and have the same datasheet
>   specifications.

Plus the datasheet should be updated soon:)